# Vue <a> tag href attribute splicing

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My current url is `http://localhost:8080/component`, and in this page I have an `<a>` tag

```
<a :href="'/detail/' + comp._id"></a>
```

When `comp._id` is determined, for example it is `6221add333182348e1d70104`.

I want the URL to jump to `http://localhost:8080/component/detail/6221add333182348e1d70104` when I click on the link.

But actually it is `http://localhost:8080/detail/6221add333182348e1d70104`.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: simply remove first / in href url

Comment: It seems doesn't work @Saeid Doroudi

Comment: You able to add component to the link. `<a :href="'/component/detail/' + comp._id"></a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `/component/`to your link. Like: `<a :href="'/component/detail/' + comp._id"></a>`

Comment: The original is spliced relative to the root URL, is there any method relative to the current URL?

Comment: @lai9fox One dot and slash (`./path`)  would relative to the current path

Comment: @lai9fox And it works with `./`?

Comment: No, I have try `./`, `../`, none of them work. It still jump to `http://localhost:8080/detail/6221add333182348e1d70104`@Maik Lowrey

Comment: Relative paths depend on the current path. You'll need to tell us that.